# Missing extension - explorer issue?

Tags: windows-explorer, jpeg

In this picture, right at the bottom you can see **Files of type:**
Then it says **Pictures (*.bmp, *.png, *.jpg, *.gif)**

[image: Screenshot]

My question is, how can I add the extension **.jpeg** in there?

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an Explorer issue.** Even though you see the standard "Open file" dialog provided by Windows shell, the filters are specified by **the program  that displays it**, and in most cases you *cannot* change them except by patching that program – or asking the developers to fix the fillter. (The official page for mIRC bug reports seems to be [the forum](http://forums.mirc.com/ubbthreads.php/ubb/postlist/Board/8/page/1).)

However, you can *temporarily override* these filters. Just enter `*.jpeg` or `*.jpg;*.jpeg` (or even `*` for all files) in the *File name* box and press Enter or *Open*.